# Block element with height: 100%; & wrapper element – content overlaps

Tags: css, html

I am trying to figure out how to combine HTML5 markup & the layout of my website, which does not work as expected.

The header of my website is set to `height: 100%` to fill the complete screen: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh1q68m/1/).

Now, according to the [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element), the `main` element should be used to markup the main section of a website:

> The main element represents the main content of the body of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document or central functionality of an application.

This is where my trouble starts.
As soon as I add the `main` element or any other block element to wrap my content, the header does not have the correct height anymore: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh1q68m/2/)

I understand that this is because the `height: 100%;` on the header refer to the parent – the `main` element in this example. Since there is no height declared, the `height: 100%;` rule has no reference.

To fix this, I have to declare `height: 100%` also on the `main` element: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh1q68m/3/)

Now the problem is: Since the `main` element is there to mark up the main content of the page, things like navigation & footer elements don't belong in there:

> The main content area of a document includes content that is unique to that document and excludes content that is repeated across a set of documents such as site navigation links, copyright information, site logos and banners and search forms (unless the document or applications main function is that of a search form).

If I add content below the `main` element, that content overlaps the `main` element, because it fills all available space: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh1q68m/6/)

I already played around with setting various height declarations on the footer, but without any luck.

Also, I tried various `overflow` declarations, with limited success (double scrollbar): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh1q68m/7/)

Is there a fix for that – would be a shame if the markup wouldn't be compatible with the layout?

Comment: I am a bit confused what your actual goal is - can you light things up for me?

Comment: why are you putting the header in the main and why is your header going to be 100% height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you fiddle really is all over the place, i'll be honest. It's mainly due to you nesting elements that aren't designed to be nested. (i.e. headers should be in your main, they should be above it, etc).

Your structure should be something like:

```
<header>
</header>

<main>
</main>

<footer>
</footer>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/3Lh1q68m/8/)

---

You then need to look a your positioning of your page.

So, header is always at the top, and your footer is always "at the bottom of the main". Since i've only placed a `min-height` onto my main, this should solve that issue of 'overlapping' (since main will go to the height it needs to automatically).

So, you would need to **set a height of your header**

```css
header,footer{
  background:red;
  height:150px;
  }

main{
  min-height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<header>head</header>
<main>main content</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

---

Your overall markup would hence be something like:

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/3Lh1q68m/10/)

Or, alternatively:

This snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.myHeader {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}
footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
}
main {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="myHeader"> <b>Header</b>

  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Footer Content</p>
</footer>
```